# Everytime my internet is disconnected, XP asks me to connect

Tags: windows-xp, windows-networking

I keep my internet disconnected when not in use. I completed the Windows XP wizard of `Set up a home or small office network`. Since then whenever I'm disconnected from internet and an application asks Windows for net, a pop up is displayed asking to connect to net. Before I did the wizard it didn't used to ask. The network I created using the wizard is showing under `Entire Network`->`Microsoft Windows Network`, but it's not giving me option to delete.
How to make Windows stop asking me to connect to internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in Internet Properties in Control Panel. On the Connections tab there are three radio options, and selecting `Never dial a connection` should stop it harassing you:

[image]